# What is the Missing code in this Wolfram Blog article?

Tags: image-processing

Here's a very cool [Wolfram Blog Article](http://blog.wolfram.com/2009/04/24/droste-effect-with-mathematica/) with incomplete code, that can apply the Droste Effect to an image is various interesting ways.  Copying this code, in the journal doesn't provide a working solution.  What's missing here to get this code to work?

```
InitializeSources[source_, p1_, p2_] := 
 Quiet[Block[{imgbytes = Import[source, "Byte"],
sourcebytestream},
If[imgbytes === $Failed, $Failed,
  sourcebytestream = FromCharacterCode[imgbytes];
  LaunchKernels[];
  DistributeDefinitions[OriginalValueFns,
   DrostifyRegion, ReplicateRegion, TransformCoordinates,
   CropData];
  ParallelEvaluate[$ImageInterpolationFn = 
    OriginalValueFns[CropData[
      Reverse@Developer`ToPackedArray[
        N[ImportString[#, {"JPG", "Data"}]]], p1, p2]/255.];] &[
sourcebytestream]]]
]

OriginalValueFns[data_] :=
 ($AspectRatio = 1/Apply[Divide, Most[Dimensions[data]]];
  Apply[Function, {{x, y}, 
    If[Abs[x] > 1 || Abs[y] > $AspectRatio, {1., 1., 1.}, #] &[
     Table[ListInterpolation[
        data[[All, All, channel]], {{-1, 1}, $AspectRatio {-1, 1}},
    InterpolationOrder -> 1][x, y], {channel, 1, 3}]
 ]}]);

DrostifyRegion[start_, end_, res_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=

 Image[Table[
 Apply[$ImageInterpolationFn, 
    TransformCoordinates[{x, y}, opts]], {x, end, 
    start, -2/(res - 1)}, {y, -$AspectRatio/$AspectRatio, 2/res}]
];

DrosteImage[resolution_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
ImageAssemble[
ParallelTable[
 {DrostifyRegion[-1 + 2 (slice - 1)/#, -1. + 2 slice/#,
   resolution, opts]},
 {slice, #, 1, -1}]] &[Max[Length[Kernels[]], 1]
];

(*Find the center of the selected rectangle*)
$DrosteScale = Max[Flatten[{Abs[r2 - center]/(center - {1, 1}), Abs[r1 - center]/
 Abs[Reverse@Take[Dimensions[data], 2] - center]}]];
CropData[data_, r1_, r2_] := Block[{center, xlo, xhi, ylo, yhi, innerdims},
center = Mean[{r1, r2}];

(*Find the scaling of the cropped image to the rectangle*)

innerdims = Abs[r1 - r2]/$DrosteScale;
{{ylo, xlo}, {yhi, xhi}} = Round[{center - innerdims/2, center + innerdims/2}];
Return[data[[xlo ;; xhi, ylo ;; yhi, All]]]];

TransformCoordinates[{x_, y_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := FixedPoint[
ReplicateRegion, {Re[#], 
  Im[#]} &@((OptionValue[
     Zoom] E^(I OptionValue[Rotation])) (OptionValue[XShift] + 
     I OptionValue[YShift] + x + 
     I y)^(OptionValue[CopiesPerRotation] + 
     OptionValue[Spirals] I  Log[$DrosteScale]/(2 \[DoubledPi]))),
OptionValue[MaxRecursion]];
Options[TransformCoordinates] =
{Zoom -> 1, XShift -> 0, YShift -> 0, Rotation -> 0,
CopiesPerRotation -> 1, MaxRecursion -> 10, Spirals -> 1};

ReplicateRegion[{x_, y_}] := Which[
(*If outside the image area, move closer*)

Abs[x] > 1 || Abs[y] > $AspectRatio,
    {x, y} $DrosteScale,
(*If inside the frame move out to the main image*)

Abs[x] < $DrosteScale &&
    Abs[y] < $DrosteScale $AspectRatio,
    {x, y}/$DrosteScale,
(*otherwise use the calculated coordinates*)
True, {x, y}
];
```

Comment: Well, good work copying all that code out, I guess. Still, I can't help thinking that maybe you would be better off just to e-mail Jon McLoone?

Comment: @OleksandrR. Good Idea.  If the geniuses here at the stack can't help. I'll see if John want's the points ;)

Comment: It's not a _Mathematica_ Journal article, it's a Wolfram Blog article.

Comment: @m_goldberg correct, and changed

Comment: You have a few transcription errors. No fun finding them. At least three.

Comment: the blog post looks to be using Mathematica 7 - weren't a lot of image processing functions introduced in Mathematica 8?

Comment: @belisarius Thanks for the proofread. Found the transcription errors and fixed the posted code.

Comment: @RHall Did you ever get this code working?  If so I could re-open this for you to self-answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No it never happened,   Please do re-open this question.   thanks very much for asking!